# Web form with master page, cant go to cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, redirect

I have this page and it has user.master page. on the user master page I have Cart button and SignIn button.
I cannot redirect to the mentioned pages without filling the Form, Is it possible to make redirection without filling the form?
please advice, I couldn't find any explanation on the web.
[My screenshot with explenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boa9j.jpg)

```
<!-- Board Match Start -->
    <div class="container relativeSignUpImage">
        <h3>Board Matcher</h3>
        <h4>The best way to find a board that fits your needs.</h4>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <div class="center-page">
            <label class="col-xs-11">What size of wave will you ride this board on?</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <%--<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Knee to waist high" GroupName="wSize" value="1"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Waist to chest high" GroupName="wSize" value="2"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="Chest to head high" GroupName="wSize" value="3"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" Text="Overhead" GroupName="wSize" value="4"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" Text="Double overhead plus" GroupName="wSize" value="5"/>--%>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="wSize" class="form-control" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Knee to waist high</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Waist to chest high</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Chest to head high</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Overhead</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Double overhead plus</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>    
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorwSize" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please choose wave size" ControlToValidate="wSize"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <label class="col-xs-11">What type of wave do you ride?</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="wType" class="form-control" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Soft and mushy</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Rolling</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Pitching and fast breaking</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Hollow and barrelish</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please choose wave type" ControlToValidate="wType"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <label class="col-xs-11">What is your surfing style?</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" name="styleCB" runat="server" Text="Simple Cruising" /><br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" name="styleCB" runat="server" Text="On the Nose" />
                <br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" name="styleCB" runat="server" Text="Wide Carves" />
                <br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" name="styleCB" runat="server" Text="Fast Cuts & Snaps" />
                <br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" name="styleCB" runat="server" Text="Big Airs" />
                <br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" name="styleCB" runat="server" Text="Getting Barreled" />

            </div>
            <label class="col-xs-11">What do you wish to accomplish?</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="trickSuitable" class="form-control" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Learn to surf</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Catch more Waves</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Nail more tricks</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Try something CRAZY!</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select achievment " ControlToValidate="trickSuitable"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <label class="col-xs-11">How skilled are you?</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="skillReq" class="form-control" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Wishing to start</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Beginner</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Intermediate</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Advanced</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Sponsored</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please choose your skill level " ControlToValidate="skillReq"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>

            <label class="col-xs-11">Enter your weight in kilo.</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbLweight" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Your weight" CausesValidation="True" type="number" min="25" max="100"></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please type your weight " ControlToValidate="tbLweight"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-11 space-vert">
                <asp:Button ID="btBoardMatch" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Match a board" OnClick="btBoardMatch_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="signUpImage">
            <div>
                By creating an account with<br />
                our store, you will be able to<br />
                move through the<br />
                checkout process faster,<br />
                view and track your orders<br />
                in your account and more.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Sign Up end -->
```

```
    protected void btnCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Cart.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand ur buttons trigger validation. If you don't want a button to trigger validation add the following tag

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

This is how ur cart and signin needs to look like in the master page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCart" runat="server" OnClick="btnCart_Click"  CausesValidation="false" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will try this today

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a validation group on all elements that you wish to be validated by each `RequiredFieldValidator`.

But make sure that **you do not specify** a validation group for the cart and login buttons.

Example:

```
<!-- all elements below belong to group "order" -->
<asp:DropDownList ID="wSize" class="form-control" runat="server" validationgroup="order">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Knee to waist high</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2">Waist to chest high</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="3">Chest to head high</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="4">Overhead</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="5">Double overhead plus</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>    

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorwSize" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please choose wave size" ControlToValidate="wSize" validationgroup="order"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

Comment: Thank You very much for your help!